# PreparedStatement MySQLSyntaxErrorException using valid query string

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

I've spent hours looking at what seems like what should be perfectly working code. The `connection.createStatement()` version of this method works fine but as soon as I try to convert it over to the better, `connection.prepareStatement()` version it throws a MySQLSyntaxErrorException and complains about a problem near the '?' character in my query string. The code is posted below and I simply cannot see the problem with it. The database field is VARCHAR and accepts Strings so that is not the problem.

```
    public Discussion getDbDiscussionInstance(String _instanceId) throws SQLException {

    String qryStr = null;
    PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
    ResultSet myRs = null;

    // Try to build the object with existing data.
    try {
        qryStr = "SELECT assignment_id, discussion_id, section_id, user_id, circle_id, breakout_id, title, description, created, due FROM macb_discussions WHERE instance_id=?";
        myStmt = connection.prepareStatement(qryStr);
        myStmt.setString(1, _instanceId);
        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(qryStr);
        if (rs.next()) {
            this.discussionId = myRs.getString("discussion_id");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        dbFunc.catchSQLException(e);
    } finally {
        myRs.close();
        myStmt.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: can u pls include the exact exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only  `myStmt.executeQuery();` without the argument, you have already preperad the statement

Answer (score 0):

From the docs,

[Statement.executeQuery(String sql)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)

[PreparedStatement.executeQuery()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29)

So change your function accordingly.
 `myStmt = connection.prepareStatement(qryStr);` to

```
 myStmt = connection.prepareStatement();
```